# Get column names with condition in R

Tags: r

Here is sample data:

```
A <- read.table(text = "id Person X2012 X2011 X2010 X2009 X2013 X2008 X2007
1  1   Name  1.3  NA 1.5 0.23 0.25  NA  NA
2  2   Name  NA   NA 0.1 NA   NA    NA  NA
3  3   Name  NA   NA NA  NA   NA    0.95 0.30
4  4   Name -1.69 1 0.2  NA   NA    NA  NA", header = TRUE)
```

Here what I would like to get:

```
  year id  Person X2012 X2011 X2010 X2009 X2013 X2008 X2007
1 X2009 1   Name   1.30    NA   1.5  0.23  0.25    NA    NA
2 X2010 1
3 X2012 1
4 X2013 1
5 X2010 2   Name     NA    NA   0.1    NA    NA    NA    NA
6 X2007 3   Name     NA    NA    NA    NA    NA  0.95   0.3
7 X2008 3
7 X2010 4   Name  -1.69     1   0.2    NA    NA    NA    NA
8 X2011 4
9 X2012 4
```

So basically, get the column name if numeric (if NA not) and create new row: something like `t(sort(colnames(x))`. I'm after the vector **year** itself, rest doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reshape2` to the rescue:

```
library(reshape2)
A_melt <- melt(A, id.vars=c("id", "Person"))
A_val <- A_melt[!is.na(A_melt$value), ]
A_val$variable <- as.character(A_val$variable)
A_val[with(A_val, order(id, variable)), ]

   id Person variable value
13  1   Name    X2009  0.23
9   1   Name    X2010  1.50
1   1   Name    X2012  1.30
17  1   Name    X2013  0.25
10  2   Name    X2010  0.10
27  3   Name    X2007  0.30
23  3   Name    X2008  0.95
12  4   Name    X2010  0.20
8   4   Name    X2011  1.00
4   4   Name    X2012 -1.69
```